# Powershell Find and replace string

Tags: powershell

Sorry guys,
i'm newbie on Powershell, and i'm trying to find on servers directory (asp pages) the string for certain ip, and replace for dns.

My code gives-me all strings that contains the ip, even if is a part of string. For now i'm only trying to find the exactly string.

Ex: look for 192.168.10.2, gives-me 192.168.10.2 and 192.168.10.254 and so on.

My code:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path \\server1\inetpub -Recurse -Include *.* -Exclude "*cache*","*includes*","*logs*"| 
 Where-Object {(Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "192.168.10.2" -Quiet) -eq $true} | 
 ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.FullName} | 
 Out-File C:\Users\user\Documents\result.txt
```

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Did you try `\b192.168.10.2\b`? I believe the `\b` should check for the start and end of a string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Olaf, but your suggestion on this case doesn't work

Comment: The suggestion by @Alex_P is correct, the only thing missing in there is the fact that the string to search for has dots in it and dots have special meaning in regex ('any character'). Simply escape those with a backslash to make it work (`\b192\.168\.10\.2\b`)

Comment: Thank you both, for help! Now, is working fine! the exactly string is returned